# getting the value of a textbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>JQuery Problem 2</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="problem2.js"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id="game"> 
      <form onsubmit="return false"> 
        <p> 
          Guess:
          <input type="text"/> 
          <input type="submit" value="Go"/> 
        </p> 
        <p> 
          <strong>Number of guesses:</strong> 
          <span>0</span> 
        </p> 
        <p> 
          <strong>Last guess:</strong> 
          <span>None</span> 
        </p> 
        <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" style="width: 400px"> 
          <tr> 
            <th>Guess</th> 
            <th>Result</th> 
          </tr> 
        </table> 
      </form> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

When the user enters his value i want to retrieve the numerical value that they entered in the textbox, with jQuery, how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select checkboxes using the [`:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) selector but generally I would recommend using an ID or class, as appropriate.

The value of a text box can be obtained using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

For example, this function listens for change events on all text boxes and alerts the new value:

```
$(":text").change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First I would add either a class or an ID to your input. Once you do that, you can retrieve it very easily like so:

```
var value = $('.yourClass').val();
```

or if you give it an ID:

```
var value = $('#yourID').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the unique control in the page, to assign an ID is a good practice.
For looped element such as table list, use position selector is better.